# How to recover or reinstall .vim_runtime directory and contents

Tags: vim, directory, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04, rm

I downloaded this [vim config](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) but decided later I wanted to work using vanilla vim (because i'm still not used to it).

So I followed the instructions at the bottom of the README:

> **How to uninstall**
>
> Just do following:
>
> - Remove ~/.vim_runtime
> - Remove any lines that reference .vim_runtime in
>     your ~/.vimrc

I deleted the hidden vim_runtime directory located in `:home/user/` on Ubuntu 16.04, using

```
rm -rf ~/.vim_runtime/
```

then realized this was a mistake. I now can't open vim without getting:

*Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:

line 3:

E484: Cannot open file /home/user/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim

line 4:

E484: Cannot open file /home/user/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim

line 5:

E484: Cannot open file /home/user/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim

line 6:

E484: Cannot open file /home/user/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim

Press ENTER or type command to continue*

I don't know what to do from here, It would be great if I could just purge it all and have vim as it was when you first install the OS, I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim && sudo apt-get install vim
```

but still get the same error detection when opening vim after the command has completed.

Comment: You didn't go throught the second step "Remove any lines that reference .vim_runtime in your ~/.vimrc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had no personal configuration other than that Vim distribution, just `rm /home/user/.vimrc` and start anew. You can also remove `/home/user/.vim/` if it exists. That gives you a clean slate. There's no need to reinstall Vim; that distribution presumably was just user configuration (i.e. you didn't need `sudo` to install it), whereas Vim is installed system-wide (via `apt`). If there's something inside `.vimrc` that you want to save (and you have no other editor installed), you can launch Vim with `vim -N -u NONE`.

#### soapbox

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

#### new config

I would base your personal configuration on the example that ships with Vim. You can install it like this:

```
$ vim
:edit $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example
:saveas $MYVIMRC
:quit
```

Also see `:help defaults.vim`.

Comment: :help defaults.vim just gives me "E149: Sorry, no help for defaults.vim". Thank-you very much though, in hindsight, I couldn't agree more with that soapbox.

Comment: Thanks! `defaults.vim` was introduced with Vim 8.0; you probably have an older version.